# Capabilities of Airwatch's Workspace ONE Web browser

Tags: airwatch

My company is evaluating using Airwatch for Mobile Device Management. We have some webapps (PWA / using Service Workers) we use internally. In other posts I read that the administrators may limit the use of the devices' default browsers Safari and Chrome and only allow Airwatch's Workspace ONE Web browser for internal web pages.

Now, my questions are: Does the Workspace ONE Web browser support Progressive Web Apps with service workers?
And additionally, is this browser based on another one, so I'm able to check easily what Workspace ONE Web is capable of (caniuse)?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you review the capabilities directly from VMware.  Starting here: https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-Workspace-ONE-UEM/9.7/vmware-airwatch-guides-97/GUID-AW97-Features_Matrix.html

PWA's may function differently on Workspace ONE - Web if there are specific controls implemented that could impede the PWA functionality, like local storage.  However, you'll likely be able to determine if this is a risk to your project by reading the documentation.